# Why does this implementation of multiprocessing.pool not work?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, multiprocessing, sympy

Here is the code I am using:

```
def initFunction(arg1, arg2):
    def funct(value):
        return arg1 * arg2 * value
    return funct

os.system("taskset -p 0xff %d" % os.getpid()) 
pool = Pool(processes=4)
t = np.linspace(0,1,10e3)

a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h = sy.symbols('a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h',commutative=False)

arg1 = sy.Matrix([[a,b],[c,d]])
arg2 = sy.Matrix([[e,f],[g,h]])
myFunct = initFunction(arg1, arg2)

m3 = map(myFunct,t) # this works
m4 = pool.map(myFunct,t) # this does NOT work
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
      execfile(filename, namespace)
   File "/home/justin/Research/mapTest.py", line 46, in <module>
      m4 = pool.map(myFunct,t) 
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
      return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
      raise self._value
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

So what does this error mean and how can I multiprocess this map function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Objects that you pass between processes when using `multiprocessing` must be importable from the `__main__` module, [so that they can be unpickled](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) in the child. Nested functions, like `funct`, are not importable from `__main__`, so you get that error. You can achieve what you're trying by using a [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) instead:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

def funct(arg1, arg2, value):
    return arg1 * arg2 * value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = [1,2,3,4]
    arg1 = 4 
    arg2 = 5 

    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    func = partial(funct, arg1, arg2)
    m4 = pool.map(func,t)
    print(m4)
```

Output:

```
[20, 40, 60, 80]
```

Comment: that explains it, thanks! But I noticed while testing this method, pool.map is slower than if i didn't use pool at all. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @faceforest There's a non-trivial amount of overhead required to start up the child processes, and to pickle the args for `func`, send them to the child processes, and unpickle them. If the calculations you're doing in `funct` are pretty quick to finish, the overhead you're adding may end up taking longer than the sum of all the calculations, which would make the regular map faster.

Comment: Ahh I see - this code was just a test code for a program that would use the above code for heavy calculations for 10x10 symbolic matrices, so I should expect the pool.map to improve relative to the regular map function?

Comment: @faceforest Probably, yes. But again, it depends how large the objects you have to pass between processes are, and how often you need to pass them.